# Unable to catch errors globally from inversify-express-utils controllers

Tags: node.js, express, inversifyjs

I'm using this package https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils for a nodejs app, and I want to have a place to handle errors from **any** controller, the way I know is to use [express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers),
but it doesn't seems to work in this case- nobody calls the error handler:

userController.ts

```
import {interfaces, controller, request, response, httpGet} from "inversify-express-utils";

@controller('/user')
class UserController implements interfaces.Controller {
    
    ....

    @httpGet('/')
    private async get(@request() req, @response() res) {
        throw new Error('BROKEN!');
    }
}
```

server.ts

```
....

const server = new InversifyExpressServer(container);

server.setConfig((app) => {
    ...
    
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        console.log(err); // This never called
    });

    return app;
});
```

1. Why the handler not being called?
2. There is a more elegant way to do this using the inversify-express package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `setErrorConfig` when init a server, like this:

```
server.setErrorConfig((app) => {
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err instanceof HttpRedirectError) {
        return res.redirect(err.redirectUrl);
      }
      return res.json(Requester.createError(err));
    }
    next();
  });
});
```